# parameterized types and raw types for different classes

Tags: java, generics, collections

Using raw type warning occured, how to use parameterized type for

```
List apa=(List)class1.method1(xx);
```

All the values present in the list are of `String` type.

Comment: What does method1 return, i.e. why do you cast to List?

Answer (score 2):

`List<String> apa = class1.method1(xx);`

and specify return type of `List<String>` for `method1` in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

If all present values are `String` means use like this,

```
List<String> apa  = (List<String>)class1.method1(xx);
```